# Bootstrap Slider + Rails: Multiple sliders are loaded on page load

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider, bootstrap-slider

I am using the [Bootstrap-slider gem](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider) in my Rails 4 wizard and for some reason, when I navigate to the wizard step with the slider, it shows the correct number of sliders, but once I nivagivate to the next step, and then go back to the step with the sliders, twice as many get loaded.

View:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <%= f.input :weightloss_desire, input_html: { data: 
        {provide: "slider",
            "slider-max": 10,
            "slider-min": 0,
            "slider-step": 1,
            "slider-tooltip": "hide",
            "slider-ticks": [1,10],
            "slider-ticks_positions": [0, 100],
            "slider-ticks_labels": ["Minimal", "Strong!"],
            "slider-tooltip": "hide", 
            "slider-value": @remote.weightloss_desire}
        }, label_html: {class:"block"}, label: "Weight loss desire"  %>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <%= f.input :daily_stress, input_html: { data: 
        {provide: "slider",
            "slider-max": 10,
            "slider-min": 0,
            "slider-step": 1,
            "slider-tooltip": "hide",
            "slider-ticks": [1,10],
            "slider-ticks_positions": [0, 100],
            "slider-ticks_labels": ["Minimal", "Strong!"],
            "slider-tooltip": "hide", 
            "slider-value": @remote.daily_stress}
        }, label_html: {class:"block"}, label: "Daily stress level"  %>
</div>
```

Once I refresh the page, the view reverts back and only shows 2 sliders.  Also, I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I keep seeing the warning

`bootstrap-slider.min.js:4 bootstrap-slider.js - WARNING: $.fn.slider namespace is already bound. Use the $.fn.bootstrapSlider namespace instead.`

But since I am only calling the slider inline, I'm not sure how to correct that

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. Fixed by removing Turbolinks.

Remove

> gem "turbolinks"

from your Gemfile and run bundle

Remove

> //= require turbolinks

from application.js